PC monitor loses signal when i turn on my hdmi TV thats also connected to my GPU
Have been plagued with this for a long time now, LG C2 is connected to my 4090 through hdmi, every time my pc is on and i turn on the tv, my primary monitor (have 2 through DP) loses the signal, the second one doesnt, i had this issue before but somehow it went away randomly, it only blinked black once when i turned on the tv then but did show the desktop again quick.
Installed newer drivers (ddu safe mode) and the problem is back, can bring the monitor back with ctrl+shift+win+B but i want to know why it is losing the signal? handshake issue? installed 551.86 again where it went away some time ago randomly but no luck.
When the tv/receiver is already on this doesnt happen, or when i restarted the graphics driver mentioned above i can turn the tv off and on and not even a blink.
First i thought maybe displayfusion could be the culprit, but without it running it still happens. Switched the DP cables around, tried different ones, nada.
The last time this issue stopped when i rebooted while my 2 monitors and tv were active, tried that again this time but no fix.
edit: seems switching primary to the other monitor still makes the same one lose signal.
edit2: might have found the issue, disabled the high def audio controller for the hdmi going to the tv, no black screen, enabled it again and black screen is back, went into the playback devices sound settings and somehow my LG was set to disabled, enabled it, did a couple full shutdowns and boots and not even a blink, will update if something changes, hope this was it.

And the problem is back after a night's sleep, didnt change anything, now the LG shows as unplugged even though its on but not active on windows (as in im not showing the desktop on it, its just on) , yesterday i did 5 hard boots and it showed enabled without being active, i dont get it anymore. Unplugged the hdmi, removed the hd audio controller in device manager and rebooted to get it back, nothing works.

Seems fixed, monitor (Acer X34A) has a DP deep sleep option, turned it off and quick start on, no more issues.
